# PostgreSQL setting for autoquoting indentifiers

Tags: postgresql, case-sensitive

I have a software that should work with different RDBMS types (SQLite, PostgreSQL, SQL Server and maybe Oracle), and, unfortunately, in the source code, the table names are expressed in this form

ExampleOfTableName

As I would like that such naming is maintained in all of the RDBMS, simply for a matter of taste, I am in trouble with PostgreSQL that requires the name is written like this

"ExampleOfTableName"

in order to be considered with the given case.

Now this is a problem because I should modify my software in order to query (or create also) the tables like this

select * from "ExampleOfTableName"

in order to comply with PostgreSQL, but this is clearly a lot of work that I would like to avoid.

Is there any setting in PostgreSQL so that it considers the identifiers as they where all quoted?

I found a

#quote_all_identifiers = off

in the settings, but seems it does not solve.

Thanks

Comment: "*that requires the name is written like this*" - which is required by the SQL standard. The best advice I can give you: **never** quote any identifiers (neither using the standard compliant double quotes `"` nor any DBMS specific "quotes", like SQL Server's square brackets)

Comment: In PostgreSQL you do not have to quote identifiers of the kind that you show, they just get interpreted as if in lower-case. Problems arise when you have non-syntactical names, like those starting with numbers, or when you have names that are distinguished by case: ExampleOfTableName and exampleoftablename.